Does allow_methods of CorsLayer of tower_http work?
this is 8080 server, it configured with CORS layer:
use axum::{serve, Router};
use axum::http::{HeaderValue, Method, };
use axum::response::{Html, IntoResponse};
use axum::routing::get;
use tokio::net::TcpListener;
use tower::ServiceBuilder;
use tower_http::compression::CompressionLayer;
use tower_http::cors::CorsLayer;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let service = ServiceBuilder::new()
        .layer(CompressionLayer::new())
        .layer(CorsLayer::new().allow_methods([Method::PUT])
            .allow_origin(
                "http://localhost:8081".parse::<HeaderValue>().unwrap(),
            ));
    let router = Router::new()
        .route("/", get(handler))
        .layer(service.into_inner());

    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8080").await.unwrap();
    println!("127.0.0.1:8080");
    serve(listener, router).await.unwrap();
}

async fn handler () -> impl IntoResponse {
    Html("8080 returing")
}

this is 8081 server, it serves a html page:
use axum::{serve, Router};
use tokio::net::TcpListener;
use tower_http::services::ServeDir;
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let router = Router::new()
        .fallback_service(ServeDir::new("web"));
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8081").await.unwrap();
    serve(listener, router).await;
}

8081 server serves a html page, this page would automatic call 8080 server:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sty.css"></link>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p> 8081 </p>
    <label id="lb"></label>
    <script>
        const lb = document.getElementById("lb");
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8080")
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => lb.innerHTML = data)
            .catch(err => lb.innerHTML = err);
    </script>
</body>
</html>

from this the web page of 8081, it can get response from 8080 by GET method, but 8080 server only allows PUT method from CORS, GET method is supposed to be not allowed
I have checked ”allow_origin“ method， it works,
but allow_methods not works, does my code wrong?
